# My seeder in the Migration Configuration class locks the application (Asp.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seeding

I have the following Migration configuration class:

```
namespace MVC_Authentication.Migrations
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using MVC_Authentication.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal sealed class MigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public MigrationConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        ContextKey = "MVC_Authentication.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        SeedDatabase(context).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    protected async Task SeedDatabase(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
    {
        var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(ctx));

        if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator") == null)
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));

        if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("User") == null)
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("User"));

        ApplicationUserManager userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ctx));

        var user_Admin = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            UserName = "Admin",
            Email = "myEmail",
            EmailConfirmed = true
        };
        if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(user_Admin.UserName) == null)
        {
            await userManager.CreateAsync(user_Admin, "MyPassword");
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin.Id, "User");
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin.Id, "Administrator");
        }
    }
}
```

}

but when the execution arrives at:

```
if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator") == null)
```

the application locks and I can wait and wait.
Maybe I should not use RoleManager and UserManager here? It's the only way to seed roles and users.
Thanks for any hint of what possible can go wrong.

Comment: Will you try the synchronous version if it behaves the same way? `roleManager.FindByName()`

Comment: the intellisense gives me no synchronous version FindByName()

Comment: Try RoleManager instead of ApplicationRoleManager; `var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
                    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);`

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Comment: oh I didn't know that would be the fix, haha. I added the answer, please mark it as the correct one, thank you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the synchronous method in RoleManager instead of in ApplicationRoleManager;

```
var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
roleManager.FindName(...);
```